# Continous deployment trigger by commiter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server

As we all know, we can make filters at releases i.e. to release only if a build succeeded with a commit in a specific branch.

[image: CD Trigger]

Is it somehow possible to start a release, only if a specific person has made the commit?

**Something like a continous release by author**.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, you can use 'Build.RequestedFor' [build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) and [custom conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). You can skip jobs if user display name is not of your user. You can define a custom condition on the job level like the following (just update User_display_name to needed value):

[image]

Or as text:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.RequestedFor'], 'User_display_name'))
```